# How to define generic type functions during variable definition?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to parse markdown files for my own blog.

While I can define separate functions to parse the frontmatter of the markdown files after import, I saw people are doing this style of code:

```
export const mods = /*#__PURE__*/ import.meta.glob<
  true,
  any,
  {
    getHeadings: () => {
      depth: number;
      text: string;
      slug: string;
    }[];
    getFrontMatter: () => {
      title?: string;
      sectionTitle?: string;
      order?: number;
      section?: string;
      sectionOrder?: number;
      subsection?: string;
    };
  }
>("./docs/**/*.{md,mdx}", {
  eager: true,
  query: {
    meta: ""
  }
});
```

[`glob` import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) is a Vite-specific function for importing multiple files together.

I am trying to understand the syntax. From what I can tell, this is defining a function as generic type for the imported file lists, so that each file imported can use that function.

What I don't understand is the structure - what does `true`, `any` do?

I cannot find anything from the `glob` document, or Google.
Could anyone help to explain?

Comment: A "table"?! That's an _object_. Start with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html.

Comment: Please [edit] to ask a single specific question; right now there are multiple and the question risks being closed as needing focus.  Both questions presumably depend on some knowledge of solid-js (especially "why the functions..."), so you might want to tag the question as such.  If you are really asking a pure TS question without meaning to depend on third-party code, then please provide a self-contained [mre] where all necessary code is included in the text of the question and not only linked externally.  Good luck!

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, I'm not a ts guy, may misuse some of the terms. I read the generics already, but the question seems to be a bit different -- I'm not even sure this is a generic-related one, but that's my closest guess.

Comment: true and any are generic parameters/type parameters, which _are_ discussed in the docs linked.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. What I'm confused is in the link, the `Type` defined in `<>` are matching the parameters in `()`. But the code above is not this case? What are the corresponding parameters for `true` and `any`? And it seems there're more types in `<>` than the parameters in `()`...

Comment: There's absolutely no requirement to have a 1:1 match between generic/type parameters and actual parameters. To find out how both kinds of parameters are used don't look at where it's _called_, look at where it's _defined_ and _implemented_.